# Upgrade magento 2.2.3 to 2.2.8 fatal error

Tags: magento2, plugin, magento2.2.3, magento-upgrade, magento2.2.8

Hi I upgrade my magento 2.2.3 to 2.2.8 where I have some custom functionality for emails.

After upgrading am getting

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Mail\Message\Interceptor::clearFrom() 

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Mail\Message\Interceptor::getRawContent()
```

I have made plugin for public function `\Magento\Email\Model\Transport`

```
 beforeSendMessage(\Magento\Email\Model\Transport $subject)
        { 
           $message = $subject->getMessage()
           $body = $message->getBody()->getRawContent();
           $message->clearFrom();
           $message->setBody($bodyNew);
        }
```

its `\Magento\Framework\Mail\Message`

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

buddy I just check that class I'm also gonna share as well that class 
 
`Magento\Framework\Mail\Message;`

```
<?php
/**
 * Mail Message
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Magento\Framework\Mail;

class Message extends \Zend_Mail implements MessageInterface
{
    /**
     * @param string $charset
     */
    public function __construct($charset = 'utf-8')
    {
        parent::__construct($charset);
        $this->setHeaderEncoding(\Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64);
    }

    /**
     * Message type
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $messageType = self::TYPE_TEXT;

    /**
     * Set message body
     *
     * @param string $body
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBody($body)
    {
        return $this->messageType == self::TYPE_TEXT ? $this->setBodyText($body) : $this->setBodyHtml($body);
    }

    /**
     * Set message body
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBody()
    {
        return $this->messageType == self::TYPE_TEXT ? $this->getBodyText() : $this->getBodyHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Set message type
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setMessageType($type)
    {
        $this->messageType = $type;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

so as you can see that there is no any function `getRawContent()` or `clearFrom()` so they may updated that as well in the updated version thats why its not working

Comment: this is really bad :(

Comment: you fixed?this isssue